# Excel.ExcelReaderFactory cannot open some files

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I'm getting this error trying to open some xls files using the Excel.ExcelReaderFactory (http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/)

```
IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);

excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = false;
DataSet spreadsheetDocument = excelReader.AsDataSet();
```

> Error: Neither stream 'Workbook' nor 'Book' was found in file

The error occures when you call CreateBinaryReader

Some files work 100%, but others give this exception.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Similar question on their site (http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/discussions/461766)

Comment: I did a compare between a file that works and a file that doesn't.  The file that doesn't work has the following right at the bottom:    Crystal Decisions  Powered by Crystal

Comment: It would be wise to post your question in there discussion forum

Comment: Thanks - I'll do that as well

Comment: Do you have a file that causes the issue and a code sample?

Comment: I've added code - can this question be unheld?

Comment: Unfortunately the files we get contain sensitive data.  If I open them in Excel and remove the data and resave them, the problem goes away.  It seems that the files are generated from Crystal Reports and although they are Excel files, and can be opened in Microsoft Excel, the binary is very different to a standard Excel file.

Comment: The work around for now, until I can get a full answer on this is to use Microsoft.Interop - open the file, save it and close it - then use the ExcelDataReader to read it.  That unfortunately completely voids the reason for using ExcelDataReader in the first place as we wanted to get away from using Microsoft.Interop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/discussions/461766#post1113133 thought I'd post it here:

Same problem, same exception with crystal report xls file. 
This because 'Excel Data Reader' defines block strings as "Workbook" and "Book", instead Crystal Report as "WORKBOOK": you have to do a case insensitive comparison!

open "Excel\Core\BinaryFormat\XlsRootDirectory.cs" and replace line 75

```
if (e.EntryName == EntryName)
```

with

```
if (string.Equals(e.EntryName, EntryName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
```

for me it solved.

have a nice day, 
marco

Comment: Getting a new exception now:   BIFF Stream error: Buffer size is less than entry length.  on line 32 in XlsBiffRecord.cs

Comment: Added ReadOption.Loose to the CreateBinaryReader parameters    _excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream, ReadOption.Loose); and now it works 100%

Comment: one of my client try to upload excel and I found "BIFF Stream error: Buffer size is less than entry length" entry in my log DB, so I want to know when this error occurred ? (it's working fine for all other file).